# Precedence for Haproxy Timeouts

Tags: haproxy

If I have below config in my `haproxy`. I want to understand what values will take precedence for the timeouts? I have checked the docs but couldn't get anything conclusive

```
defaults
    log global
    timeout connect 30000ms
    timeout client 300000ms
    timeout server 300000ms
backend ttyy
    timeout connect 60000ms
    timeout server 600000ms
```

If a request comes in how much time it will wait for the connection to set up and how much time it will wait for a server response